# how to add onItemClick in my Listview that get data from MYSQL with Asynctask

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview, android-asynctask

I'm a beginner with Android Programming. I just want to ask how can i add onItemClick in My Listview with Asynctask. here is the code

```
 public class ListUser extends Activity {
 private String jsonResult;
 private String url = "http://gspelocator.net46.net/test/list_user.php";
 private ListView listView;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_list);
  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  accessWebService();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 // Async Task to access the web
 private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
   try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
      response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
   }

   catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  }

  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
   String rLine = "";
   StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

   try {
    while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     answer.append(rLine);
    }
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   return answer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   ListDrwaer();
  }
 }// end async task

 public void accessWebService() {
  JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
  // passes values for the urls string array
  task.execute(new String[] { url });
 }

 // build hash set for list view
 public void ListDrwaer() {
  List<Map<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("users");

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String username = jsonChildNode.optString("username");
    String telp = jsonChildNode.optString("telp");
    String outPut = username + " - " + telp;
    userList.add(createUser("users", outPut));
   }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, userList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "users" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);


 }

 private HashMap<String, String> createUser(String username, String telp) {
  HashMap<String, String> userNameTelp = new HashMap<String, String>();
  userNameTelp.put(username, telp);
  return userNameTelp;
 }
}
```

here's the XML file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ListUser" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >
</ListView>
```

and when I click on item, i want to open another Activity and send "username" from that listview to my php code :

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['username'];

$con=mysql_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx");
mysql_select_db('xxx', $con);


$date = date('Y-m-d');

$query = "SELECT * from table WHERE username = '.$user.' AND timestamp like '%$date%'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $records[]= $row;
}

mysql_close($con);
$data = "{\"users\" : ".json_encode($records)."}";
echo $data;
?>
```

How can i do that? please help me.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve listItem click in following manner.

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){

ItemClicked item = adapter.getItem(position);

Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,Activity2.class);
//based on item add info to intent
startActivity(intent);

}
});
in your adapters getItem you have to write
public ItemClicked getItem(int position){

return items.get(position);
}
```

where I am calling Intent you can execute your AsyncTask. :)

Comment: where should i put the code? i just put your code after setAdapter code in AsyncTask. but i got error message "OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type" and "The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})"

Comment: You have to put into your onCreate() method.

Comment: put it within On create

Comment: ok, i've put it to my onCreate method, now i get another lint error on `ItemClicked item = adapter.getItem(position);` 
they says :
- ItemClicked cannot be resolved to a type
- The method getItem(int) is undefined for the type AdapterView<capture#1-of ?>

Comment: sorry @viren where should i write that code? after `listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);` ?

Comment: its a method. put it just before your last bracket.

Comment: @viren i've put it through, i got some problem on the getItem method, **ItemClicked cannot be resolved to a type** and i add the parameter to my activity, am i wrong? and on the `return items.get(position);` what is the items? my listview? or what? i got an error to on that **items cannot be resolved** i really don't get it. thanks

Comment: items would be your ListView. Before proceeding you should create a little demo to understand the concepts. Please Go through some examples.

Comment: @viren thank you so much, now i get the concept after through some examples, and it works on my project :)
and i want to ask, is it possible to send data to php and get data from php in 1 class and 1 asynctask?